# Selects aninhados em jquery ou javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho uma tabela dinâmica com desdobramento de parcelas e gostaria de alterar os valores dos selects baseados pelo seu antecessor, exemplo.

[image: forma de pagamento com select]

- Caso selecione o primeiro item gostaria que os subsequentes assumissem a mesma forma escolhida.
- outro exemplo escolhi o primeiro como depósito os demais teria que ser depósito, mas caso na segunda linha escolhesse boleto a primeira permaneceria depósito e apenas as próximas assumissem como boleto.

Isso é possível?

```html
<table id="table_com_parcelas" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-responsive table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="align">Parcela</th>
      <th class="align">Vencimento</th>
      <th class="align">Valor</th>
      <th class="align">Forma pagamento</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="align">1 de 10</td>
      <td class="align">14/10/2017</td>
      <td class="align">R$ 1.000,00</td>
      <td class="align"><select id="select-1"><option value="1">Boleto</option><option value="2">Cartão</option><option value="3">Cheque</option><option value="4">Dinheiro</option><option value="5">Transferência</option></select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="align">2 de 10</td>
      <td class="align">13/11/2017</td>
      <td class="align">R$ 1.000,00</td>
      <td class="align"><select id="select-2"><option value="1">Boleto</option><option value="2">Cartão</option><option value="3">Cheque</option><option value="4">Dinheiro</option><option value="5">Transferência</option></select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="align">3 de 10</td>
      <td class="align">13/12/2017</td>
      <td class="align">R$ 1.000,00</td>
      <td class="align"><select id="select-3"><option value="1">Boleto</option><option value="2">Cartão</option><option value="3">Cheque</option><option value="4">Dinheiro</option><option value="5">Transferência</option></select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="align">4 de 10</td>
      <td class="align">12/1/2018</td>
      <td class="align">R$ 1.000,00</td>
      <td class="align"><select id="select-4"><option value="1">Boleto</option><option value="2">Cartão</option><option value="3">Cheque</option><option value="4">Dinheiro</option><option value="5">Transferência</option></select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="align">5 de 10</td>
      <td class="align">11/2/2018</td>
      <td class="align">R$ 1.000,00</td>
      <td class="align"><select id="select-5"><option value="1">Boleto</option><option value="2">Cartão</option><option value="3">Cheque</option><option value="4">Dinheiro</option><option value="5">Transferência</option></select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="align">6 de 10</td>
      <td class="align">13/3/2018</td>
      <td class="align">R$ 1.000,00</td>
      <td class="align"><select id="select-6"><option value="1">Boleto</option><option value="2">Cartão</option><option value="3">Cheque</option><option value="4">Dinheiro</option><option value="5">Transferência</option></select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="align">7 de 10</td>
      <td class="align">12/4/2018</td>
      <td class="align">R$ 1.000,00</td>
      <td class="align"><select id="select-7"><option value="1">Boleto</option><option value="2">Cartão</option><option value="3">Cheque</option><option value="4">Dinheiro</option><option value="5">Transferência</option></select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="align">8 de 10</td>
      <td class="align">12/5/2018</td>
      <td class="align">R$ 1.000,00</td>
      <td class="align"><select id="select-8"><option value="1">Boleto</option><option value="2">Cartão</option><option value="3">Cheque</option><option value="4">Dinheiro</option><option value="5">Transferência</option></select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="align">9 de 10</td>
      <td class="align">11/6/2018</td>
      <td class="align">R$ 1.000,00</td>
      <td class="align"><select id="select-9"><option value="1">Boleto</option><option value="2">Cartão</option><option value="3">Cheque</option><option value="4">Dinheiro</option><option value="5">Transferência</option></select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="align">10 de 10</td>
      <td class="align">11/7/2018</td>
      <td class="align">R$ 1.000,00</td>
      <td class="align"><select id="select-10"><option value="1">Boleto</option><option value="2">Cartão</option><option value="3">Cheque</option><option value="4">Dinheiro</option><option value="5">Transferência</option></select></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

segue tabela.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você já usa jquery favor remover a linha que adiciona o script.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_com_parcelas" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-responsive table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="align">Parcela</th>
      <th class="align">Vencimento</th>
      <th class="align">Valor</th>
      <th class="align">Forma pagamento</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="align">1 de 10</td>
      <td class="align">14/10/2017</td>
      <td class="align">R$ 1.000,00</td>
      <td class="align"><select id="select-1"><option value="1">Boleto</option><option value="2">Cartão</option><option value="3">Cheque</option><option value="4">Dinheiro</option><option value="5">Transferência</option></select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="align">2 de 10</td>
      <td class="align">13/11/2017</td>
      <td class="align">R$ 1.000,00</td>
      <td class="align"><select id="select-2"><option value="1">Boleto</option><option value="2">Cartão</option><option value="3">Cheque</option><option value="4">Dinheiro</option><option value="5">Transferência</option></select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="align">3 de 10</td>
      <td class="align">13/12/2017</td>
      <td class="align">R$ 1.000,00</td>
      <td class="align"><select id="select-3"><option value="1">Boleto</option><option value="2">Cartão</option><option value="3">Cheque</option><option value="4">Dinheiro</option><option value="5">Transferência</option></select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="align">4 de 10</td>
      <td class="align">12/1/2018</td>
      <td class="align">R$ 1.000,00</td>
      <td class="align"><select id="select-4"><option value="1">Boleto</option><option value="2">Cartão</option><option value="3">Cheque</option><option value="4">Dinheiro</option><option value="5">Transferência</option></select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="align">5 de 10</td>
      <td class="align">11/2/2018</td>
      <td class="align">R$ 1.000,00</td>
      <td class="align"><select id="select-5"><option value="1">Boleto</option><option value="2">Cartão</option><option value="3">Cheque</option><option value="4">Dinheiro</option><option value="5">Transferência</option></select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="align">6 de 10</td>
      <td class="align">13/3/2018</td>
      <td class="align">R$ 1.000,00</td>
      <td class="align"><select id="select-6"><option value="1">Boleto</option><option value="2">Cartão</option><option value="3">Cheque</option><option value="4">Dinheiro</option><option value="5">Transferência</option></select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="align">7 de 10</td>
      <td class="align">12/4/2018</td>
      <td class="align">R$ 1.000,00</td>
      <td class="align"><select id="select-7"><option value="1">Boleto</option><option value="2">Cartão</option><option value="3">Cheque</option><option value="4">Dinheiro</option><option value="5">Transferência</option></select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="align">8 de 10</td>
      <td class="align">12/5/2018</td>
      <td class="align">R$ 1.000,00</td>
      <td class="align"><select id="select-8"><option value="1">Boleto</option><option value="2">Cartão</option><option value="3">Cheque</option><option value="4">Dinheiro</option><option value="5">Transferência</option></select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="align">9 de 10</td>
      <td class="align">11/6/2018</td>
      <td class="align">R$ 1.000,00</td>
      <td class="align"><select id="select-9"><option value="1">Boleto</option><option value="2">Cartão</option><option value="3">Cheque</option><option value="4">Dinheiro</option><option value="5">Transferência</option></select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="align">10 de 10</td>
      <td class="align">11/7/2018</td>
      <td class="align">R$ 1.000,00</td>
      <td class="align"><select id="select-10"><option value="1">Boleto</option><option value="2">Cartão</option><option value="3">Cheque</option><option value="4">Dinheiro</option><option value="5">Transferência</option></select></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Ele pega o evento change do select, pega qual é o seu valor e seu índice e a partir daquele item ele muda os valores dos próximos selects

```
$(function(){
  var selects = $("#table_com_parcelas select");
  var index = null;
  var valor = null;
  selects.on('change', function() {
     var valor = this.value;
     indice = selects.index(this);
     selects.each(function( index ) {
            if(index > indice){
             $( this ).val(valor);
        }
     });
  });
});
```

Lembrado que este código deve esta dentro da tag script e debaixo do jquery.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar um jQuery bem curto pra isso:

```
1.    el_select = "#table_com_parcelas select"; // seleciono o id da tabela com a coleção dos selects
2.    $(el_select).on("change",function(){ // evento onchange dos selects
3.      n_valor = $(this).val(); //pego o valor do select alterado
4.      for(x=$(this).index(el_select)+1;x<$(el_select).length;x++){ //faço um loop alterando os selects subsequentes
5.          $(el_select+":eq("+x+")").val(n_valor);
6.      }
7.    });
```

```js
el_select = "#table_com_parcelas select";
$(el_select).on("change",function(){
 n_valor = $(this).val();
 for(x=$(this).index(el_select)+1;x<$(el_select).length;x++){
  $(el_select+":eq("+x+")").val(n_valor);
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_com_parcelas" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-responsive table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="align">Parcela</th>
      <th class="align">Vencimento</th>
      <th class="align">Valor</th>
      <th class="align">Forma pagamento</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="align">1 de 10</td>
      <td class="align">14/10/2017</td>
      <td class="align">R$ 1.000,00</td>
      <td class="align"><select id="select-1"><option value="1">Boleto</option><option value="2">Cartão</option><option value="3">Cheque</option><option value="4">Dinheiro</option><option value="5">Transferência</option></select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="align">2 de 10</td>
      <td class="align">13/11/2017</td>
      <td class="align">R$ 1.000,00</td>
      <td class="align"><select id="select-2"><option value="1">Boleto</option><option value="2">Cartão</option><option value="3">Cheque</option><option value="4">Dinheiro</option><option value="5">Transferência</option></select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="align">3 de 10</td>
      <td class="align">13/12/2017</td>
      <td class="align">R$ 1.000,00</td>
      <td class="align"><select id="select-3"><option value="1">Boleto</option><option value="2">Cartão</option><option value="3">Cheque</option><option value="4">Dinheiro</option><option value="5">Transferência</option></select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="align">4 de 10</td>
      <td class="align">12/1/2018</td>
      <td class="align">R$ 1.000,00</td>
      <td class="align"><select id="select-4"><option value="1">Boleto</option><option value="2">Cartão</option><option value="3">Cheque</option><option value="4">Dinheiro</option><option value="5">Transferência</option></select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="align">5 de 10</td>
      <td class="align">11/2/2018</td>
      <td class="align">R$ 1.000,00</td>
      <td class="align"><select id="select-5"><option value="1">Boleto</option><option value="2">Cartão</option><option value="3">Cheque</option><option value="4">Dinheiro</option><option value="5">Transferência</option></select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="align">6 de 10</td>
      <td class="align">13/3/2018</td>
      <td class="align">R$ 1.000,00</td>
      <td class="align"><select id="select-6"><option value="1">Boleto</option><option value="2">Cartão</option><option value="3">Cheque</option><option value="4">Dinheiro</option><option value="5">Transferência</option></select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="align">7 de 10</td>
      <td class="align">12/4/2018</td>
      <td class="align">R$ 1.000,00</td>
      <td class="align"><select id="select-7"><option value="1">Boleto</option><option value="2">Cartão</option><option value="3">Cheque</option><option value="4">Dinheiro</option><option value="5">Transferência</option></select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="align">8 de 10</td>
      <td class="align">12/5/2018</td>
      <td class="align">R$ 1.000,00</td>
      <td class="align"><select id="select-8"><option value="1">Boleto</option><option value="2">Cartão</option><option value="3">Cheque</option><option value="4">Dinheiro</option><option value="5">Transferência</option></select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="align">9 de 10</td>
      <td class="align">11/6/2018</td>
      <td class="align">R$ 1.000,00</td>
      <td class="align"><select id="select-9"><option value="1">Boleto</option><option value="2">Cartão</option><option value="3">Cheque</option><option value="4">Dinheiro</option><option value="5">Transferência</option></select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="align">10 de 10</td>
      <td class="align">11/7/2018</td>
      <td class="align">R$ 1.000,00</td>
      <td class="align"><select id="select-10"><option value="1">Boleto</option><option value="2">Cartão</option><option value="3">Cheque</option><option value="4">Dinheiro</option><option value="5">Transferência</option></select></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```